# How to get entire Graph in ArangoDB?

Tags: arangodb, arangojs

Using arangojs ArangoDB driver.

```
const db = new Database();
const graph = db.graph("some-graph");
const data = await graph.get();
// data only contains general information about the graph
```

How to get entire graph, including data nodes and edges, as JSON ?

Answer (score 0):

Try [the tutorial](https://www.arangodb.com/tutorials/tutorial-node-js/) where you issue a traversal query and get the results.

Comment: This solution does not seem to work.